# Error in Running NLRX (NetLogo) in Manjaro (Arch) Linux

Tags: r, linux, netlogo, manjaro, rnetlogo

I am attempting to run an NLRX simulation in Manjaro Linux (RNetLogo wouldn't work for some reason either), and am running into the following error when attempting to set up an dummy experiment:

```
    cp: cannot stat '~/.netlogo/NetLogo 6.1.1/netlogo-headless.sh': No such file or directory
    sed: can't read /tmp/Rtmpj15Yf7/netlogo-headless365385fb4bdc0.sh: No such file or directory
    sed: can't read /tmp/Rtmpj15Yf7/netlogo-headless365385fb4bdc0.sh: No such file or directory
    sh: /tmp/Rtmpj15Yf7/netlogo-headless365385fb4bdc0.sh: No such file or directory
    Error in util_gather_results(nl, outfile, seed, siminputrow) : 
      Temporary output file /tmp/Rtmpj15Yf7/nlrx5493_1365385ab03157.csvnot found. On unix systems this can happen if the default system temp folder is used.
                    Try reassigning the default temp folder for this R session (unixtools package).
    In addition: Warning message:
    In system(NLcall, wait = TRUE) : error in running command
```

Given that I am running R 4.0.0, the Unixtools package doesn't work, so that's out of the question. How would I go about fixing this?

Code for those curious:

```
library(nlrx)

netlogopath <- file.path("~/.netlogo/NetLogo 6.1.1")
modelpath <- file.path(netlogopath, "app/models/Sample Models/Biology/Wolf Sheep Predation.nlogo")
outpath <- file.path("/home/out")
nl <- nl(nlversion = "6.0.3",
         nlpath = netlogopath,
         modelpath = modelpath,
         jvmmem = 1024)
nl@experiment <- experiment(expname="wolf-sheep",
                            outpath=outpath,
                            repetition=1,
                            tickmetrics="true",
                            idsetup="setup",
                            idgo="go",
                            runtime=50,
                            evalticks=seq(40,50),
                            metrics=c("count sheep", "count wolves", "count patches with [pcolor = green]"),
                            variables = list('initial-number-sheep' = list(min=50, max=150, qfun="qunif"),
                                             'initial-number-wolves' = list(min=50, max=150, qfun="qunif")),
                            constants = list("model-version" = "\"sheep-wolves-grass\"",
                                             "grass-regrowth-time" = 30,
                                             "sheep-gain-from-food" = 4,
                                             "wolf-gain-from-food" = 20,
                                             "sheep-reproduce" = 4,
                                             "wolf-reproduce" = 5,
                                             "show-energy?" = "false"))
nl@simdesign <- simdesign_lhs(nl=nl,
                              samples=100,
                              nseeds=3,
                              precision=3)
results <- run_nl_all(nl = nl)
```

R Version for those who may want it:

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.0                         
year           2020                        
month          04                          
day            24                          
svn rev        78286                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
nickname       Arbor Day
```

Answer (score 0):

In case others find this helpful: I have encountered similar errors as the result of file path misspecification. For instance, double check model path. You may need to drop `app/`.